# Form Submission Redirect Issue

Tags: php, html

Did not work...I added the following:
    Your inquiry has been sent!

';
    header('Location: index.php'); die ();
    }

```
index.php code

<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) {
echo($_SESSION['success']);
unset($_SESSION['success']);
}
?>
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

Once you have redirected them, your page cannot show them anything anymore.

Whatever message you want to show, will now have to reside on the page they are being sent to, which in your case is `index.php`.

**P.S.** The same applies the other way around: once you have sent any information to the browser (via `echo`, `print_r`, `var_dump` or any other way) you cannot redirect them anymore.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please *always, always, always* surround your `if` statement blocks with curly braces. You will avoid much pain.

```
if ($sent) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Second of all, by changing the header, you are redirecting the user to a different page. Execution of the current script stops, and then `index.php` is executed, so your print statement never is never executed.

If you want to show a message, you need to store it in a way that persists across requests. One way to do that is to use the `$_SESSION` superglobal ([see here for more info](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)) when the form submits in your script, and then display whatever is stored in `$_SESSION` in index.php. Something like this may work: (warning: coded in the browser. use at your own risk.)

```
//in your form processing code
if ($sent) {
    $_SESSION['success'] = '<p class="error">Your inquiry has been sent!</p>';
    header('Location: index.php');
}

//in index.php
//render your page
if (isset($_SESSION['success']) {
    echo($_SESSION['success']);
    unset($_SESSION['success']);
}
```

Comment: Thats not quite there, execution of the page does not halt when a call to `header` is made, it simply sends a location directive in the response to the client. The client then interprets that and redirects the user to the new path. You should make sure you `exit()` or `die()` after your call to `header()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
if($sent)
{
  header('Location: index.php?e=inquiry_sent'); 
  exit();
}
```

Remember to show the message after of send the form:

```
if (isset($_GET['e']))
{
    if ($_GET['e'] == "inquiry_sent")
    {
        print '<p class="error">Your inquiry has been sent!</p>';
    }
}
```